# What is the most effective workflow for this iOS app?

Tags: ios, workflow, logic

I have an app that requires internet for syncing a webservice to a local core data db.  Then a local db fetch is used to populate different objects for a MapView and a TableView in a tabbarcontroller.  Im looking at these 2 scenarios:

[image: AppFlowLogic]

The main advantage of "A" is that I dont have to preload the app with a database, although its a small db (about 100 records).  The problem is that it gets convoluted.  If there is no internet connection, in MapView, the user sees a map but the refreshButton is disabled.  So thats not a problem.  But the user can still go to the tableview and he will see an empty table.

The main advantage of "B" is that with a preloaded db, the app will always have a data source ready for plotting and listing.  I dont really know how to preload the app with a db though.

I kind of want to go the first route, "A".  My main question is, since right now I disabled the refreshButton on MapView so that it only works once the data is gotten from the web...that sortedArray is empty on launch.  So if the user goes to the TableVC it will be empty.  As it stands, the user must first tap the refresh button before going to the tableview.

What is the most effective way to deal with this?

Comment: Edge cases, they are such a pain to code for, but they are so important for the user experience. I think "A" is your best option (my opinion). You could block the use of the entire app with a "You need to download the data, get an internet connection" if you have no initial data + no connection. You could write code to handle the "no data" scenario on every screen the user can get to when they have no data. Most tables contain a "no data" case which adds a row that informs the user. The best answer depends on your use cases and requirements and usually is biased by personal preference.

Comment: Thanks Dilip, I actually wish there was an xcode module to handle logic, to show you what it is according to your code because Im very visual. DBD, although I should learn how to code for first launch scenarios and such, I do think the user should have internet connection required.  Im not so sure about blocking the entire app but at least "no data" scenario.  Although, that is essentially the same thing as blocking the entire app because they wont see anything but the shell. Then again, in UX terms, its better to let them see something.  So Im stumped :( I guess I need to go the hard route

Comment: Ok Im posting a comment in the answer below because Ive advanced somewhat. But Id like your input on it because its still related to your comment. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 100 records are static enough that you can ship a default set of records with the app, that would be the best solution. The user, with or without internet, gets a populated tableview.

Ship your records as a plist in your app's bundle. On first launch, open the plist and add each entry as a new object into core data. This type of "seeding" happens very quickly. Just create a collection (array, dictionary) for the plist, then enumerate through, mapping it to your managedObject's attributes.

There's code that shows you how to do this in the WWDC 2012 video iCloud and Core Data (just ignore the iCloud part).

Then if there's a connection after the seeding, you can sync data, which would update/replace/etc the pre-populated data.

Comment: Ok thanks for the preloaded data.  The records are basically store locations. A new record gets added about every month or so.

Comment: So I cant ship it with a preloaded Core Data db?

Comment: No. Core data adds a bunch of tables and relationships and all sorts of special things to the sqlite database that can only be done when you actually go through core data to do it in your app. Be careful of any blog posts that show you otherwise! But don't worry, the seeding is not nearly as bad as you may think.

Comment: Well, you CAN, Apple does it in some of their sample code (CoreDataRecipes), but you would still have to write the seeding code  and create the sqlite the same way as seeding, on a device/simulator, copy the sqlite that gets created to the bundle, remove the seeding code from your app. And even then, I'd be skeptical. Apple's recommended procedure is to seed as described above.

Comment: I use this technique, even though I don't use CoreData. This is a good pattern for loading seed data. I copy data from a plist file to the documents folder.

Comment: Ok I check first run and take plist into NSDictionary like this: https://gist.github.com/quique123/5120205.  So now I loop thru this dictionary to fill in my CD?

Comment: I ask because I because I already have a class that does 2 things; fetches from web && parses fetched JSON data by saving it to disk, looping thru it and erasing it.  So Im thinking I could hijack that process and insert the plist file reading code on the first run.  But Im not sure what file is being saved.  Could someone look at this Parse code I have.  I posted it as the ParseClass to the same above gist.

Comment: Ok I was able to read a plist & fill my db. Its blazing fast & I LOVE [NSManagedObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:NSDictionary] :) So I pre fill db, set AppDelegate MyLocations object because I need it to hold a distance property which I can only get once I have the userLocation. In both viewcontrollers I will kick off a web sync & if successful, I must replace pre filled with latest data using SyncEngine. I will need to replace AppDelegate.MyLocations from a new db fetch. Is this AppDelegate singleton pattern the best way? Otherwise Id have to do it repetitively for each view controller.